# Changing the default icon in Netbeans' native deployment feature for Java apps

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, installation

I know the question is very long, but in a nutshell it's just that. As you know Netbeans has a feature with the help of inno setup that allows the creation of .exe installers of Java applications. The problem is that I would like to change the default icon it has (a grey java icon) for a custom one.

I have searched a lot through both Stack and Google and I haven't found anything. The closest it got is to change it via Launch4j. The thing is if it is possible to do it within Netbeans.

Furthermore, I was wondering if there is a possibility to add several languages to the installer and some other features like the creation of a desktop icon. I guess if the option exists it would be in the same place as the change-icon... but I am completely lost regarding this issue.